# SQL/C# Windows App - Several Counts From One DataSet?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a C# Windows app with an SQL table holding voter information. One of the stored fields is 'Party' with stored values of 'Dem', 'Rep', 'Ind', 'Other'. I want to total by these values and use the count function to show total of all records. I know how to use count to get the total of all the records in the the record set but how do you count each value in the field.

I have a form with textboxes for Total Records, Total Dem, Total Rep, Total Ind and Total Other. There is a list box with radio buttons. The default button is 'All' showing all records. There is a radio button for each of the values (Dem, Rep, Ind and Other). When the radio buttons are selected the list is narrowed by the selection. The total in the textboxes does not change and always shows the total for each value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way would be to build a scalar function for each count.  Something like

```
select @return = count(party) where party = 'Dem'
```

And then a view that holds the counts for each party.  There are more performant ways to do this but from your question it sounds like your just getting up off the ground and this would probably be the most straightforward way for you.

Learn about scalar functions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

And views here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

A better way (for the database) would be to build a view that uses "group by" but it would return rows instead of columns which will create a little more work for you when setting the values to each of your c# controls.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: tofutim's approach below is the exact same theory but keeps you from having to build scalar functions.  it puts it all into a single statement.

Comment: I noticed someone voted it down.  I'm guessing they don't like scalar functions.  The reason why I say use a scalar function is then you can call that function alone for text boxes, or in the view for a combined result set.  The view is only going to call each function once, so you don't get the usual performance hit of functions.  A group by is better but based on the question level, I knew that would be harder for the person who asked to work with.  Sometimes you do it the right way, and sometimes just getting it done is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS total, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Party = 'Dem' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS demTotal, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Party = 'Rep' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS repTotal, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Party = 'Ind' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS indTotal, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Party = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS otherTotal
FROM MyTable
```

Something like following would work and place the data in columns.  Depending on the size of the data, however, this may not be the most efficient.  Probably a simple group by would work the best (just tally up the results after you get them).

```
SELECT Party, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Party
```

**Update:** Make sure that Party is indexed!